# multi join mysql query taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables as below ,i am trying to join these tables but the query is taking too long to execute.Please tell me how do i optimize this.
Trying to do below

1) using a sub query i am creating a table based on input date range

2) i require to group result based on bank then on district and then on state,so that i can filter results on front end as State-->District-->Bank

3) Also i need to avoid some junk data which i am doing using not like clause.

```
select substring(a.ifsc,1,4) as code,
       s.new_state as state, 
       s.state_id as stid,
       d.new_dist as dist,
       b.ifbank as bank,
       count(a.amt) as num,
       sum(a.amt) as amt from 
             (SELECT * FROM mtr where orgdate between '$fdate_new' and '$tdate_new') 
       as a JOIN ifsc b on b.ifscd=a.ifsc 
       JOIN user c on a.excd=c.mtr 
       JOIN state_mapping s on b.state=s.org_state 
       JOIN dist_mapping d on b.dist=d.org_dist 
       where 
             s.state_id ='$stid' and 
             TRIM(d.new_dist) <> '' and 
             d.new_dist IS NOT NULL 
       group by bank,dist order by amt desc;
```

dist_mapping table

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| org_dist | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| new_dist | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

ifsc table

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ifscd   | varchar(11) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| ifscbr  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ifbank  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| newifsc | varchar(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dist    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

state_mapping table

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| org_state | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| new_state | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state_id  | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

user table

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| excode  | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mtr  | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| exname  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc mtr;
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| excd    | int(2)              | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| orgdate | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| amt     | double(12,2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| obank   | int(1)              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| brcd    | int(5)              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| brname  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rname   | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bname   | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| baddr   | varchar(60)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mob     | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ifsc    | varchar(12)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery takes more time compare to join Please try this

```
select substring(a.ifsc,1,4) as code,
       s.new_state as state, 
       s.state_id as stid,
       d.new_dist as dist,
       b.ifbank as bank,
       count(a.amt) as num,
       sum(a.amt) as amt 
       From  mtr  as a 
       JOIN ifsc b on b.ifscd=a.ifsc and orgdate between '$fdate_new' and '$tdate_new'
       JOIN user c on a.excd=c.mtr 
       JOIN state_mapping s on b.state=s.org_state 
       JOIN dist_mapping d on b.dist=d.org_dist 
       where 
             s.state_id ='$stid' and `enter code here`
             TRIM(d.new_dist) <> '' and 
             d.new_dist IS NOT NULL 
       group by bank,dist order by amt desc;
```

Comment: still the query is taking same time,do i need to create index on any column?